# Swift 5 If name of [[object]] contains one or more values of another array

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting

Need help with statements, i have **[[object]?]** which contains **name** field (struct below), and array with **types**.

```
let _object = [[object]]
```

I want to return true/false if **_object** contains one or more values from **types** array

**types array**

```
let types = ["jewelry_store", "liquor_store", "shopping_mall", "clothing_store", "store"]
```

**_object representation**

[image]

i got just `var _object = places.map{$0.typePlaceSet} //[[object]?]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two sets from each array and see if they intersect

```
let typesSet: Set<String> = ["jewelry_store", "liquor_store", "shopping_mall", "clothing_store", "store"]

let objectSet: Set<String> = _object.flatMap { $0.name } 

return !objectSet.isDisjoint(with typeSet)
```